# How to count rows of a group and add groups of count zero in Spark Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark in Scala, with `Dataset`s, and I'm facing the following situation. (*EDIT: I've rewritten the examples to be more concrete. This is meant to be put in a method and reused with different datasets.*)

Suppose we have the following Dataset, representing moves between region `a` to region `b`, at specific timestamps:

```
case class Move(id: Int, ra: Int, rb: Int, time_a: Timestamp, time_b: Timestamp)

val ds = Seq(
  (1, 123, 125, "2021-07-25 13:05:20", "2021-07-25 15:05:20"),
  (2, 470, 125, "2021-07-25 00:05:20", "2021-07-25 02:05:20"),
  (1, 470, 125, "2021-07-25 02:05:20", "2021-07-25 04:05:20"),
  (3, 123, 125, "2021-07-26 00:45:20", "2021-07-26 02:45:20"),
  (3, 125, 123, "2021-07-28 16:05:20", "2021-07-28 18:05:20"),
  (1, 125, 123, "2021-07-29 20:05:20", "2021-07-30 01:05:20")
).toDF("id", "ra", "rb", "time_a", "time_b")
  .withColumn("time_a", to_timestamp($"time_a"))
  .withColumn("time_b", to_timestamp($"time_b"))
  .as[Move]
```

What I want is to count the number of moves for each day, so that I can get an origin-destination matrix with some time divisions. Also, I want to be able to apply some labels/categories along those time divisions. (The code for how this categorization is made isn't relevant, we can just assume here it works and each category is described in a `val categs: Seq[TimeCategory]`). This could be done like this:

```scala
case class Flow(ra: Int, rb: Int, time: Long, categ: Long, inflow: Long, outflow: Long)

val Row(t0: Timestamp, tf: Timestamp) = ds.select(min($"time_a"), max($"time_b")).head
val ldt0 = t0.toLocalDateTime()
val ldtf = tf.toLocalDateTime()
val unit = ChronoUnit.DAYS
val fmds = ds.map({
  case Move(id, ra, rb, ta, tb) => {
    val ldta = ta.toLocalDateTime()
    val ldtb = tb.toLocalDateTime()
    (
      id, ra, rb,
      unit.between(ldt0, ldta),
      unit.between(ldt0, ldtb),
      TimeCategory.encode(categs, ldta),
      TimeCategory.encode(categs, ldtb)
    )
  }
})
val outfds = fmds
  .groupBy($"ra", $"rb", col("time_a").as("time"), col("categ_a").as("categ"))
  .agg(count("id").as("outflow"))
  .withColumn("inflow", lit(0))
val infds = fmds
  .groupBy($"ra", $"rb", col("time_b").as("time"), col("categ_b").as("categ"))
  .agg(count("id").as("inflow"))
  .withColumn("outflow", lit(0))
val fds = outfds
  .unionByName(infds)
  .groupBy("ra", "rb", "time", "categ")
  .agg(sum("outflow").as("outflow"), sum("inflow").as("inflow"))
  .orderBy("ra", "rb", "time", "categ")
  .as[Flow]
```

and that would yield the following result:

```
+---+---+----+-----+-------+------+
| ra| rb|time|categ|outflow|inflow|
+---+---+----+-----+-------+------+
|123|125|   0|   19|      1|     1|
|123|125|   1|   13|      1|     0|
|123|125|   1|   14|      0|     1|
|125|123|   3|   11|      1|     0|
|125|123|   3|   12|      0|     1|
|125|123|   4|   12|      1|     0|
|125|123|   5|   14|      0|     1|
|470|125|   0|   21|      1|     0|
|470|125|   0|   22|      1|     2|
+---+---+----+-----+-------+------+
```

The problem is, if I wanted to get the average inflow per day for each pair of regions, many days with inflow = 0 would be missing. For example, if the following agg is done:

```
fds.groupBy("ra", "rb", "categ").agg(avg("inflow"))
// output:
+---+---+-----+-----------+
| ra| rb|categ|avg(inflow)|
+---+---+-----+-----------+
|123|125|   14|        1.0|
|123|125|   13|        0.0|
|470|125|   21|        0.0|
|125|123|   12|        0.5|
|125|123|   11|        0.0|
|123|125|   19|        1.0|
|125|123|   14|        1.0|
|470|125|   22|        2.0|
+---+---+-----+-----------+
```

For `125 -> 123` and category `12`, the avg was `0.5`, but considering the start and end timestamp of the whole dataset, there should be 5 days with category `12`, not just 2. The avg should be `1 / 5 = 0.2`. This second case is what I want to calculate. Considering I want to calculate other agg functions too (like stddev), I suppose the most flexible alternative would be to "fill" the rows whose values should be zero. What is the best of way - in terms of performance/scalability - of doing that?

*(EDIT: I thought of a better approach here as well.)* So far, a possible solution that comes to my mind is to create another `DataFrame` with the "time slots" (in this case, each "slot" would be a day index with all suitable categories) and do one more union, like this:

```scala
// TimeCategory.encodeAll basically just returns
// every category that suits that timestamp
val timeindex: Seq[(Long, Long)] = (0L to unit.between(ldt0, ldtf))
  .flatMap(i => {
    val t = ldt0.plus(i, unit)
    val categCodes = TimeCategory.encodeAll(categs, unit, t)
    categCodes.map((i, _))
  })
val zds = infds
  .select($"ra", $"rb", explode(typedLit(timeindex)).as("time"))
  .select($"ra", $"rb", col("time")("_1").as("time"), col("time")("_2").as("categ"),
    lit(0).as("outflow"), lit(0).as("inflow"))
val fds = outfds
  .unionByName(infds)
  .unionByName(zds)
  .groupBy("ra", "rb", "time", "categ")
  .agg(sum("outflow").as("outflow"), sum("inflow").as("inflow"))
  .orderBy("ra", "rb", "time", "categ")
  .as[Flow]
  .show()
fds.groupBy("ra", "rb", "categ")
  .agg(avg("inflow"))
  .where($"avg(inflow)" > 0.0)
  .show()
```

and the result:

```
+---+---+----+-----+-------+------+
| ra| rb|time|categ|outflow|inflow|
+---+---+----+-----+-------+------+
|123|125|   0|   17|      0|     0|
|123|125|   0|   18|      0|     0|
|123|125|   0|   19|      1|     1|
|123|125|   0|   20|      0|     0|
|123|125|   0|   21|      0|     0|
|123|125|   0|   22|      0|     0|
|123|125|   1|    9|      0|     0|
|123|125|   1|   10|      0|     0|
|123|125|   1|   11|      0|     0|
|123|125|   1|   12|      0|     0|
|123|125|   1|   13|      1|     0|
|123|125|   1|   14|      0|     1|
|123|125|   2|    9|      0|     0|
|123|125|   2|   10|      0|     0|
|123|125|   2|   11|      0|     0|
|123|125|   2|   12|      0|     0|
|123|125|   2|   13|      0|     0|
|123|125|   2|   14|      0|     0|
|123|125|   3|    9|      0|     0|
|123|125|   3|   10|      0|     0|
+---+---+----+-----+-------+------+
only showing top 20 rows

+---+---+-----+-----------+
| ra| rb|categ|avg(inflow)|
+---+---+-----+-----------+
|123|125|   14|        0.2|
|125|123|   12|        0.2| // <- the correct avg
|123|125|   19|        1.0|
|125|123|   14|        0.2|
|470|125|   22|        2.0|
+---+---+-----+-----------+
```

Is it possible to improve this?

Comment: Without any table `join`, how would you generate a dataset `involving other columns besides a time "index"` after performing `groupBy/agg`?  In particular, what will these "other columns" be like for the rows consisting of the "gap dates"?  Perhaps some sample output data would help clarify.

Comment: i would suggest explore window functions: [window function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-window-functions/)

Comment: Just to be sure: how big is your data once the `agg(count("id"))` is done? Because if it's not billions of rows, you can collect it and compute the average, filling holes, directly on the driver with scala collections. I say this because many people forget that *once the data is reduced to a few MB*, using a complex distributive framework like spark is overkill. And you can always recreate the spark dataset afterward, e.g. to display or write it somewhere using spark.

Comment: @Juh_ it's intended to be a method in a library, so it should work for larger datasets too. But, after `agg(count(id))`, looking at common use cases, it really shouldn't get to billions of rows.

Comment: @LeoC I'll edit the question with more meaningful examples and an updated approach I have in mind

Comment: I don't have a better solution to your question that what your propose. But for the average, you can use your min/max code and divide count by `lit(max - min)`.

Answer (score 1):

I can only propose a little improvement to your initial solution, to replace join with unionByBame. It should be more efficient than join, but I didn't test performance:

```
val ds = Seq(
  1L -> java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-25 13:05:20"),
  2L -> java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-25 00:05:20"),
  1L -> java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-25 02:05:20"),
  3L -> java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-26 00:45:20"),
  3L -> java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-28 16:05:20"),
  1L -> java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-29 20:05:20")
).toDF("id", "timestamp")

val ddf = ds
  .withColumn("day", dayofmonth($"timestamp"))
  .drop("timestamp")

val r = ds.select(min($"timestamp"), max($"timestamp")).head()
val t0 = r.getTimestamp(0)
val tf = r.getTimestamp(1)

val idf = (t0.getDate() to tf.getDate()).toDF("day")
  .withColumn("id", lit(null).cast(LongType))

ddf.unionByName(idf)
  .groupBy($"day")
  .agg(sum(when($"id".isNotNull, 1).otherwise(0)).as("count"))
  .orderBy("day")
  .show
```

Comment: I used your suggestion of using `unionByName` in my solution ;) thanks